# Passing parameter from template to view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

A Django noob here.
I'm stuck with my problem regarding exporting csv in django. I'm currently successfully exporting a csv file containing all the objects(Product) in the database using this function in views.py of my Model Product.

```
def export_csv(request):

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="product-inventory.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Product Name', 'STATUS'])

    products = Product.objects.all().values_list('name', 'status')

    for product in products:
        writer.writerow(product)

    return response
```

This is in my template

```
<a class="export-btn" id="test" href="{% url 'export_csv' %}">Export</a>
```

And this is the url.py

```
url(r'^export/csv$', product_views.export_csv, name='export_csv')
```

The question is how can I change dynamically the `Product.objects.all()` in my `export_csv` function so that it will be equal to the product list obtained from the user using search (using request.GET in another function)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "in another function"? If you mean in a separate view then that won't work, you need to pass in the get parameters in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in template form:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
     <input type="text"  name="q" placeholder="Search">
     <input type="submit" value="Search">
 </form>
```

Now in view you can get search value and filter products:

```
search = request.GET.get('q')
products = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=search).values_list('name', 'status')
```

Comment: Hi, I already have this in my form and it search successfully. I just want to pass the exact list of products from the search to my function that exports csv file.

Comment: @GGWordPress do you mean that you have search field on one view and you want to pass it's result to another one? Is it OK for you to use one view?

Comment: I don't know if I understand but yes. I have request.GET in one view.py function that results to a list of products.

Comment: @GGWordPress I mean you can just do it in one view. You have view with search form export_csv(). You can check  inside it `if request.GET.get('q')` perform export otherwise do nothing.